# iOS8 Suggested apps - Do I need bluetooth on?

Tags: bluetooth, ios8, core-location, ibeacon

iOS8 introduced 'Suggested Apps' based on location. Research tells me that it works off GPS as well as iBeacon, with a major difference. For GPS triggered suggestions, you should not have the app installed. For iBeacons triggered ones, however, you should already have the app installed (and I'm assuming you should have run it at least once to register for geofencing notifications in CoreLocation)

My question is, do you need Bluetooth on for iBeacon triggered notifications to work? Or am I being too optimistic to think that Apple might have a daemon low-energy process that does bluetooth spoofing, even when bluetooth is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need bluetooth enabled for `CoreLocation` to detect beacons.  You can easily verify this yourself by using a beacon detector app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8), and see if you can find any beacons with bluetooth turned off.  You can't.

As far as 'Suggested Apps' goes, I have seen no evidence that it works with beacons -- only with GPS.  There is a similar feature in iOS 8 that shows an icon for an installed app on the lock screen whenever that app is launched into the background by a `CoreLocation` region monitoring event (either beacon-based or geofence-based.)  While this looks similar, it is simply part of `CoreLocation` and not part of 'Suggested Apps'.

Comment: Thanks David, I indeed tested and confirmed that you need Bluetooth on, and it does suggest apps (if installed) based on iBeacons. (So if you start geofencing using iBeacon region, and you are in the vicinity of a beacon that matches this region, you get the suggestion on your home screen.)

Comment: That sounds correct.  But this is fundamentally different from the AppStore's suggested apps feature, which shows icons for apps you don't even have installed.  Tapping on these icons shows brings up the AppStore app.